# Displaying errors, var_dump and so on of PHP with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, xdebug

I'm developing with Symfony 2. The thing is that not always I can see the errors or `var_dumps` that I use to debug. I can see them if I go to inspector->network and select the proper file and this is very annoying.

How could I see it directly to the browser?

I use Xdebug.

I have in my php.ini:

```
display_errors = On
```

And I tried with:

```
xdebug.force_display_errors = 1;
xdebug.force_error_reporting = -1;
```

but that doesn't work.

Any idea?

------- Editing ------

This is an example of how i have to debug.

[image]

I have to go to inspector -> network and select the proper file. Apart of being very annoying, it is not efficient. Problem to see the full result as I cant scroll down or scroll right.

----- End Editing -----

I'd like to avoid to write any `init_set` or others options in my code if possible.

Another question... if a `var_dump` have more than 120k character or it is protected property how can I display it? So far I was changing it to public to dig in.

Comment: Symfony comes with a `dump($parameter)` function. Use it to dump what you need. You can also dump in the twig view with `{{ dump() }}`. It can take a parameter as well.

Comment: Why not use actual Xdebug and do a proper debug session (since you already have it)?

Comment: @LazyOne what do you mean with a proper debug session?

Comment: You know -- the usual: place breakpoints and stop where needed so you can evaluate variables at that point in time; step into functions etc. Interactive debug session ... and not plain-dumb "dump this variable to look at it later when script is done running".

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways to resolve your issue. First - you can directly use under your class namespace `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);`, (but this is a not a best practice) or try to find the same string in your `php.ini` file and set it to `E_ALL`

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
```

And finally you need to restart your web server.

About your second question - use [Symfony Var Dumper](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html) for nice data output. Note that var-dumper sometimes is not compatible with old symfony versions. Use var-dumper 3.4 for best compatibility.

Comment: Hi @Deadpool
I have in php.ini the next

error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
display_errors = On

So I believe that is good.
Regarding the Var Dumper.. I dont want to add bundles to the project. I had hope to sort it out without adding any code or files into the project

Comment: @Zenit please insure that error_reporting line is uncommented

Comment: Yes. It is uncommented.